# Discord.JS inviteCreated event?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there a way to do X action when member creates invite. Like, when invite is being created, I can take Invite, code and member who created one and do some stuff with this?

Example usage (how I see this):

```js
client.on('inviteCreated', (member, invite) => {
    //stuff
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I am probably blind. Feel dumb now.

Comment: The event is `inviteCreate` not `inviteCreated`

Comment: There is event like that?! Need to check this....

Comment: Yes. See the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-inviteCreate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [inviteCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-inviteCreate) event

```
client.on("inviteCreate", invite => {
 ...
});
```